# Can we replace apache webserver with any of Wso2 Component

Tags: wso2, webserver, wso2-api-manager, f5, wso2-esb

Am totally new to Wso2 world.

Currently our system is like below.

F5 load balancer -> Apache webserver -> App Server.

Can we do it in below fashion

F5 -> wso2 -> Domain

All the hits to f5 has to route directly to our Domain instead of going to apache web server.

Is it possible to achieve?

I have some knowledge with wso2 API manager where we can configure API end point which will route to configured domain.. Will that be usable in my case or is it only applicable for APIs.

Or what about Enterprise Integrator?

Appoligies me if am totally came with a wrong concept..let me know where I went wrong

Comment: You can deploy an API in API Manager by configuring the endpoint as the back end that you want to access. But can you explain, regarding the exact requirements that you are looking for

Comment: In API manager, we have a mechanism for routing hits to the back end domain which we are configuring in the endpoint. Similar to that i want to route the request directly to our domain from load balancer without going to webservers.